# How to prevent bounties being awarded to bad answers

Tags: support, bounty

I have posted a question a while ago, but I got no answers so I decided to put a bounty on it.

My question is: How I do I prevent someone gaining the bounty point with a 
bad / stupid / invalid answer on my question?

Comment: Other people's rep is for them to do with as they wish.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't manually award the bounty to someone, the awarded value will be automatically cut in half and will go to the highest-voted answer that was posted after the bounty started, given that it has a score of 2 or greater.

So, if you really, really want to avoid seeing your bounty given to an answer that is bad, your option is pretty much only to downvote the answer, leave a comment about why it is bad, and hope others downvote it or at least don't upvote it to 2. If somehow it gets to 2 anyway, you'll have to be content with the fact that they're only getting half the rep for it.

Comment: [Further reading on how bounties work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: I'll add that flagging such an answer for moderator attention would also be an acceptable solution *if and only if* you suspect foul play (i.e. using alt accounts to get a +2 score to get the rep bounty). This applies to all answers of course, and not just those eligible for  a bounty.